# Simple stack interface

Tags: java, stack

I need to create and implement the following interface. Illegal operations on an empty stack should give an exception and the stack has to be able to handle any random number of elements. I also need a test program that shows how each method can be used. Can't use any Java library data structures, but arrays are fine.

```
public interface StringStack {

       int size();          // Current stack size
       boolean isEmpty();       // true if stack is empty
       void push(String element);   // Add element at top of stack
       String pop();        // Return and remove top element,
                    // exception if stack is empty
       String peek();       // Return (without removing) top element,
                    // exception if stack is empty.

}
```

(Edit:) 
So I guess what I don't understand fully is what is meant by "implementing". What do I need to do to the code above to create the stack? Or do I just create a class and then use this in it (i.e. public class Whatever implements StringStack)? Because when I try to do things like add an "if" or anything else I'd normally use in code, there's an error message. I've never done anything involving stacks (sorry that said "interfaces" before by mistake) so I'm slightly confused as to how I'm supposed to do this

Does anyone have an example of implementing a simple stack like this? I think my professor just didn't explain it well, most of my class is at least as confused as I am right now

Comment: And what's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). We'd love to help you with a specific question, but what you're asking here isn't well-defined enough.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Edited the post to clarify what I'm confused about

Comment: This is probably what they want you to do: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html

Comment: Thank you for the link - that website is golden! It's helping so much. I was completely confused about some basic things because my professor (bless his soul, very smart, but) speaks English as a third language, and he both misspoke and phrased some things very badly in the lectures. For example, at one point he said a class is used to extend an interface. Still open to tips if anyone has them but this website improved my situation about 200% @mrmcgreg